# My doctest is giving me failed example even though the output is correct

Tags: python, doctest

https://gyazo.com/672475d1961538af601bcfa2781f3ef2
As you can see, the "Got" and "Expected" list is the same, but as the order of its objects are randomized, its giving me a doctest failure. My code cannot be changed, so this randomization is inevitable. How do i fix this doctest problem. Here's the function that is not working.

```
def all_followers(data_dict, followed_user):
    """ {str: dict of {str: object}}, str -> list of str

    Returns a list containing the username of all the users in data_dict 
    that are following followed_user

    >>> all_followers(process_data(open("small_data.txt")), "katieH")
    ['tomCruise']

    >>> all_followers(process_data(open("rdata.txt")), "arrington")
    ['AccordionGuy', 'vkhosla', 'bhorowitz', 'peterfenton', 'mattcohler', 'michaelcvet', 'google', 'KatieS']

    """
    # The list to be returned, is created
    followers_list = []
    for key in data_dict:
        # Every username in data_dict and their "following" list is checked to
        # see if it matches the username of the followed_user
        if followed_user in data_dict[key]["following"]:
            # If key follows followed_user, the name of key is appended to the
            # followers_list
            followers_list.append(key)


    return followers_list
```

Comment: Please avoid links and images (and especially links to images), and instead paste the code (and resulting error messages) directly into your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to test the order, just wrap with a `sorted`.

Comment: @user3444412 you should mark this answer as the solution. That way you can give the **eph** the credit s/he deserves for answering your question.